# Maximal Value of Integral $\int_{-3}^3 \frac{f(x)}{x^3}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

Given a twice differentiable function $f:(-3,3)\to \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$\frac{(x-3)f''(x)-3f'(x)}{x^4}+\frac{12f'(x)}{x^5}\le 2.$$
Find the maximum value of $\int_{-3}^3 \frac{f(x)}{x^3}\;dx$.

---

I start by constructing $g(x) = \frac{f(x)}{x^3}$ and get the form of
$$g''(x) =\frac{(x-3)f''(x)-3f'(x)}{x^4}+\frac{12f(x)}{x^5}.$$
Therefore, $g''(x)\le 2+12\cdot \frac{f(x)-f'(x)}{x^5}$ and I had no progress from here. Any help greatly appreciated.

Edit: It should ask for the maximum value, not the minimum.

Comment: $\displaystyle g''(x) = \dfrac{f''(x)}{x^3} -  \dfrac{6f'(x)}{x^4} +  \dfrac{12f(x)}{x^5}$?

Comment: My bad, you are correct. Then I found that
$$\int_{-3}^3 g(x) dx\le \int_{-3}^3\left [2+3\cdot \frac{f''(x) - f'(x)}{x^4}\right ]dx.$$
Use Integral by Part,
$$\int_{-3}^3 g(x)dx = \frac{3f'(x)}{x^4} + 12\int_{-3}^3 \frac{f'(x)}{x^5} - 3\int_{-3}^3 \frac{f'(x)}{x^4}$$
and still have no idea.